# Ensure that type T of an interface is the class on which it is implemented

Tags: typescript

I have an generic Interface somewhat like:

```
interface IDo<T> {
  DoIt: Partial<T>;
}
```

In my case T is always the class on which the interface is being implemented. Can i somehow ensure that T is exactly and only the class it is being implemented on?

The use case is as follows:

```
class Worker implements IDo<Worker> {
  DoIt(): Partial<Worker> {
    ...
  }
}
```